# How to self host fonts and have them show up in all the Full Site Block Editor Typography options, including global styling

Tags: block-editor, fonts

I'm a designer. I can't code, but I can follow directions and do minor modifications of code that others have written.

I've been struggling on how to add self hosted fonts to my website and have them show up in the block editor typography options so I can use them in my design. I've done days of research and experimentation and most of what I've found uses the Customizer, which isn't what I need. I know just enough about coding to know that if it isn't exactly right, then it's wrong and won't work. I haven't been able to find something clear enough to allow me to know what I'm doing wrong.

I used a plugin to make a child theme of twenty twenty three. Here is the function.php that it created.

```
<?php /*

  This file is part of a child theme called 2023 Child.
  Functions in this file will be loaded before the parent theme's functions.
  For more information, please read
  https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

*/

// this code loads the parent's stylesheet (leave it in place unless you know what you're doing)

function your_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, 
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'); 

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', 
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 
      array($parent_style), 
      wp_get_theme()->get('Version') 
    );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_theme_enqueue_styles');

/*  Add your own functions below this line.
    ======================================== */
```

Here is the style.css that was also created at the same time.

```
/* 
 Theme Name:   2023 Child
 Theme URI:    
 Description:  
 Author:       Verity
 Author URI:   https://myannoyingwebsite.me
 Template:     twentytwentythree
 Version:      1.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

 /* == Add your own styles below this line ==
--------------------------------------------*/
```

Someone wrote some code for me so I could plug in my own font information, which I did. They also suggested I make a dedicated added_fonts.css file to hold them all. This sounded very reasonable to me so I made a completely blank one and put this in it.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Petrona";
    src: url("fonts/petrona/petrona-v28-latin-regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
         url("fonts/petrona/petrona-v28-latin-regular.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

They also told me I need to enqueue the file, and that's where I got stuck. I tried to follow some directions I found here and it didn't work. Or rather, the font didn't show up in the Typography Font Family.

https://hollypryce.com/enqueue/

When I did further research, there were so many different sorts of code I found that I just got lost and have no idea what is right or wrong, because I don't code.

Is my function.php file correct?

I think it looks like the child's style.css file is enqueued in the generated code. Is it or does it need enqueued also? (the font code didn't work when pasted directly into style.css either)

Does the .css file need any sort of header or is the stuff that is in the generated one just notes?

Is the code to insert the font correct?

And how do I properly enqueue it in the function.php file?

Or is all of this wrong and I need to do something else for my real goal: having self hosted custom fonts show up in the block editors' Typography Font Family selector?

Thanks!
Verity